# Mongo nested query with keys

Tags: mongodb

Need help on MongoDB nested query. Below is my mongo collection.

**Preference collection**

```
{
    "_id" : "user123",
    "preferences" : {
        "product-1" : {
            "frequency" : "Weekly",
            "details" : {
                 "email" : {
                    "value" : "On"
                }
            }
        },
        "product-2" : {
            "preferencesFor" : "mpc-other",
            "preferencesForType" : "Product",
            "details" : {
                "email" : {
                    "value" : "Off"
                }
            }
        },
        "product-3" : {
            "preferencesFor" : "mpc-other",
            "preferencesForType" : "Product",
            "details" : {
                "email" : {
                    "value" : "On"
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

**Product Collection**

```
{
    "_id" : "product-1",
     "name" : "Geo-Magazine" 
}
{
    "_id" : "product-2",
     "name" : "History-Magazine"
}
{
    "_id" : "product-3",
     "name" : "Science-Magazine"   
}
```

product-1, product-2... are keys from a Map.
The keys are stored in another collection Product Collection.
Can I create a nested query to cross-reference the product keys from another table?
I need the output in the below table format. Please suggest.

> user123 product-1 email On
>
> user123 product-2 email Off
>
> user123 product-3 email On

I tried the below but can't get result. Please suggest.

```
var cursor = db.productSummary.find();   
while(cursor.hasNext()){
    var sku = cursor.next()._id;
    var skuCol = "preferences."+sku+".details.email";
    var skuVal = "preferences."+sku+".details.email.value";
 db.marketingPreferences.find( {}, {_id:1, skuCol:1, skuVal:1});     
}
```

Comment: Can you please relook to your json doc ? I think preferences should be an array

Comment: Rohit, Thanks for the reply. Preferences is a Map<String, Preferences>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> var myCursor = db.productSummary.find();
> while(myCursor.hasNext()){   
var sku = myCursor.next()._id;    
var skuCol = "preferences."+sku+".details.email";    
var skuVal = "$preferences."+sku+".details.email.value";    
var result = db.marketingPreferences.aggregate([{"$project":{"_id":1,value:skuVal,preferences:{$literal: sku}}}],{allowDiskUse: true});
    while(result.hasNext()){ 
        printjson(result.next());    
    }      
}

Result 

{ "_id" : "user123", "preferences" : "product-1", "value" : "On" }

{ "_id" : "user123", "preferences" : "product-2", "value" : "Off" }

{ "_id" : "user123", "preferences" : "product-3", "value" : "On" }
```

Comment: I tried the above but getting this exception. uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
 "code" : 15999,
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$literal'"
}

Comment: which version you are using ?

Comment: mongodb version 2.4.6

Comment: $literal is in 2.6+, you can remove it and check

Comment: Thanks Rohit. I finally upgraded Mongo to v3.0 and it worked. One last question. How do I export the result from this query to csv instead of json?

Comment: @Krishna - check this http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between MongoDB and normal SQL DB. Firstly, when you query a MongoDB collection, it doesn't return a row as it will in a SQL db. What you get here is a document similar to JSON.

Also when you use `preferences.product-1.details.email : 1` it wont return you the word 'email', rather it will return you the value ie. `{"value" : "On" }`.

Using this: `db.preference.find({},{"_id":1,"preferences.product1.details.email.value":1})`

you will be able to get two details which are `user123` and `On` and you can get `product-1` from your previous query. You can store these values in a variable and keep printing them to obtain the table necessary. Also you would need another cursor to store the result of the second second query that you would do.

Here's what your query will produce if it was single standalone query:

`> db.preference.find({},{"_id":1,"preferences.product1.details.email.value":1})
.pretty()`

```
{
"_id": "user123",
"preferences": {
    "product-1": {
        "details": {
            "email": {
                "value": "On"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If you look at my post, I am already storing the product key in a cursor above and iterating through products querying another collection.

Comment: I understand that, but you need to store the result of your next query some where too. Simply calling the second query wont give you the result you want. Also read my answer again to understand how you can achieve your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void test(){
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = getDatadase().getCollection("product");
        MongoCollection<Document> pref = getDatadase().getCollection("pref");

        List<Document> allDocList =  collection.find().into(new ArrayList<Document>());
        for(Document doc:allDocList){
            System.out.println(doc.get("_id"));
            String preferences = doc.get("_id")+"";
            String sku = "$preferences."+preferences+".details.email.value";

            Document aggregation = new Document().append("$project", new Document().append("_id", 1).append("value", sku));
            List<Document> pipeline = new ArrayList<Document>();
            pipeline.add(aggregation);

            List<Document> aggList = pref.aggregate(pipeline).into(new ArrayList<Document>());

            for(Document doc1:aggList){
                System.out.println(doc1.append("preferences", preferences));
            }
        }
    }
```

**This Will return** 
product-1

Document{{_id=user123, value=On, preferences=product-1}}

product-2

Document{{_id=user123, value=Off, preferences=product-2}}

product-3

Document{{_id=user123, value=On, preferences=product-3}}

Comment: Thanks Rohit. Is it possible to do the same with mongo queries or functions? I need to create a roster of the above result and it could be around 2 million. Not sure if I achieve that with a Java program. There must be some way in mongo to make variables read as field/column. \n var cursor = db.productSummary.find(); 

while(cursor.hasNext()){
    var sku = cursor.next()._id;
    var skuCol = "preferences."+sku+".details.email";
    var skuVal = "preferences."+sku+".details.email.value";
 db.marketingPreferences.find({},{_id:1,'${skuVal}':1});
}

Comment: This is achievable from mongoshall but i am not sure what is the issue in my earlier ans. If you feel this ans meet your expectation can you accept it ?

Comment: In your earlier answer your last comment was you were checking in on something. It is not printing the exact result.