# mongo db nested query with wildcards and equality condition

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Trying to run a mongo db find query with equality condition in a nested VARIABLE key value

**Bonus points for pymongo solution**

```
db.utestmongo.insert({'name':'test','doc':{'heading':{'title':'awesome'},'body':{'title':'content'}}})
# want: 'title'=='awesome' => {'name':'test','doc':{'heading':{'title':'awesome'},'body':{'title':'content'}}}
# ideally
db.utestmongo.find( { "doc.*.title": "awesome" } )

# tried
db.utestmongo.find( { doc: { $elemMatch: { title: 'awesome' } } } )
```

Also tried links below, got very confused, maybe its because its not an equality query
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2989
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/
[Nested mongo query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37218627/nested-mongo-query)
[Mongo nested query with keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699502/mongo-nested-query-with-keys)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197652/how-to-find-mongodb-field-name-at-arbitrary-depth/31200456#31200456

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you wish to leave it as a find query you need to use the [where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) clause and give it a function, however i'm not sure how efficient this approach is.

another alternative is using aggregate with [objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/)
and then iterating over all the keys.
it should look like this:

```
 db.utestmongo.aggregate([
    {
      $addFields: { array: { $objectToArray: "$doc" }}
    },   
    {
      $match: {'array.v.title': "awesome"}
    }])
```

pymongo solution

```
import pymongo
db_cnxn = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = db_cnxn['db']

pipeline = [
        {"$addFields":{"array": { "$objectToArray": "$doc" }}},
        {"$match": {'array.v.title': "awesome"}}
        ]

list(db['utestmongo'].aggregate(pipeline))
```

Comment: Nice! Is possible to have it return just the `{'title':'awesome'}` part?

Comment: yes of-course,  can you clarify exactly what you want returned though?, just the title part seems meaningless as you already know the title that is matched.

Comment: `{'title':'awesome', 'more':'stuff'}` basically the closest data associated with filter value. Also can you approve my edits you have a typo in solution

Comment: Add a  [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) phase with only the fields you want.